# How to quickly read a subarray out of a source array

Tags: javascript, performance

I currently use the following:

```
const canvasOneBuffer = new Uint8Array(canvasOneImageData.data.buffer);
// within an x/y loop:
const newPixel1Data0 = canvasOneBuffer[4 * (x + y * canvasOne.width) + 0];
const newPixel1Data1 = canvasOneBuffer[4 * (x + y * canvasOne.width) + 1];
const newPixel1Data2 = canvasOneBuffer[4 * (x + y * canvasOne.width) + 2];
const newPixel1Data3 = canvasOneBuffer[4 * (x + y * canvasOne.width) + 3];
const pixel1Data = new Uint8ClampedArray(4);
pixel1Data[0] = newPixel1Data0;
pixel1Data[1] = newPixel1Data1;
pixel1Data[2] = newPixel1Data2;
pixel1Data[3] = newPixel1Data3;
```

This seems a bit obtuse though.  Is there any way I can go about creating the new `Uint8ClampedArray(4);` with a single read from the buffer array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean like

```
const pixel1Data = canvasOneBuffer.slice(0, 4)
.map(canvasItem => {
  // do what ever with canvasItem
});
```

Comment: this is plain ES6 if you need to use ES5  replace `canvasItem => {
  // do what ever with canvasItem
}` with `function(canvasItem) { // do whatever here}`